# Corresponding <UL> <LI> simultaneous hover highlight

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

Ok so a little bit of a strange one,

I have 2 ul's with an equal number of li's in each...

in jQuery I want to be able to over over either of the ul li's and see it, and its corresponding li (from the other ul) get the class "highlight"...

I though it could be done by counting the number from the top of the list?

Still no idea how to do it though.

Here is a visual representation of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#list1 > li').hover(function() {
    $('#list2 > li').eq($(this).index()).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    $('#list2 > li').eq($(this).index()).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Or if you want it in both directions:

```
$('.list > li').hover(function() {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $('.list > li:nth-child('+(idx+1)+')').addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $('.list > li:nth-child('+(idx+1)+')').removeClass('hover');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/XNRux/

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$("ul.list1>li").hover(function(){
      var ind=$(this).index();
   $(this).css("background-color","red");
   $('ul.list2 li:eq('+ind+')').css("background-color","red");
},
function(){
    var ind=$(this).index();
  $(this).css("background-color","transparent");
   $('ul.list2 li:eq('+ind+')').css("background-color","transparent");
});

$("ul.list2>li").hover(function(){
    var ind=$(this).index();
   $(this).css("background-color","blue");
   $('ul.list1 li:eq('+ind+')').css("background-color","blue");
},
function(){
    var ind=$(this).index();
   $(this).css("background-color","transparent");
   $('ul.list1 li:eq('+ind+')').css("background-color","transparent");
});
```

and Here is detailed [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNbxT/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li', 'ul.list1, ul.list2').hover(

function() {

    $('li:eq('+ $(this).index() +')', 'ul.list1, ul.list2').addClass('highlight');

},

function() {

    $('li:eq('+ $(this).index() +')', 'ul.list1, ul.list2').removeClass('highlight');

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj9hH/2/)**